# Re-write method from using Array to using ordered List

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have to write a Method twice. Once using Array and once using linked Lists. 
The task is to draw a Polygon. The points are saved in an Array or linked Lists.

I already did the first part (Array and it works perfectly)

```
public void draw() {
        Drawing.graphics.setColor(this.color);
        int[]xPoints = new int[this.points.size()];
        int[]yPoints = new int[this.points.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.points.size();i++){
            Position p = this.points.get(i);
            xPoints[i] = p.getX()+this.origin.getX();
            yPoints[i] = p.getY()+this.origin.getY();
        }
        Drawing.graphics.fillPolygon(xPoints,yPoints,this.points.size());

    }
```

Now I just don't know how do write the same Method only using linked Lists.
That's how far I've come. It's not much.....

```
public void draw() {
        Drawing.graphics.setColor(this.color);
        PolygonList list = new PolygonList(this.points.size(),this.points.size(), this.color);
            Drawing.graphics.fillPolygon(list.origin.x,list.origin.y,this.points.size());       
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `points.size()` and `points.get(i)` sounds more like list than like array

Comment: Please always show your attempt at the second solution, no matter how bad it might be. Doing this would increase the quality of the question 100-fold.

Comment: Why `LinkedList` and why not `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Don't you think you need a loop in the second solution as well...? Your question can be simplified to "how to create a list and add elements to it"...

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy code. Extract your existing code to a method with a parameter like `drawPolygon(List<Position> positions)`. So you can invoke this methode with both array and list:

```
drawPolygon(Arrays.asList(points));
drawPolygon(pointsAsList);
```